# Getting lots of undefined references when using QtNetwork components

Tags: c++, qt, networking, qt4

```
#include "QtGui"
#include "QtNetwork/QtNetwork"
#include "QtNetwork/qnetworkaccessmanager.h"
#include "QtNetwork/qnetworkrequest.h"
#include "QtNetwork/QNetworkAccessManager"
#include "QtNetwork/QNetworkRequest"

......

bool NewAccountDialog::verifyAccount()
{
    QString loginURL = "https://accounts.craigslist.org/";
    QByteArray USERAGENT = "Mozilla/Firefox 3.6.12";

    QNetworkAccessManager * manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

    QNetworkRequest request;
    request.setUrl(QUrl("http://qt.nokia.com"));
    request.setRawHeader("User-Agent", "MyOwnBrowser 1.0");
//    QNetworkRequest * request = new QNetworkRequest();

    .........
}
```

I eventually just changed it to the example qt uses for testing and I still get the problem, every method of the network classes I call I get undefined reference errors. So far this has only happened with the network components, the gui's fine so I'm wondering if it's my fault somehow.

Comment: You can format code correctly by selecting it and pressing the "code" toolbar button or indenting every line by 4 spaces. I fixed it for you this time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to link against module `network`. To do that add to `.pro` file

```
QT += network
```

Check http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtnetwork-module.html#details for reference.